# Mootools The Wall + Slimbox

Tags: hyperlink, mootools, slimbox

I am using wall.plasm.it and would like to use slimbox to open the images in fullscreen http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox

But when I add the slimbox script to my website and click on an image, it just opens the image and redirects me to the image on the server but doesnt start slimbox

Comment: It sounds like you aren't initializing slimbox correctly, so the handlers haven't been added to images. If you open a console (CTRL+ALT+J in Chrome) are there any errors?

Comment: there are no errors

i see there no code in the example for initializing slimbox
it seems it runs out of the box on links with rel=lightbox? http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox

Comment: That is indeed the way it should work. Are you also including mootools? Could you perhaps put up some code on jsbin or similar?

Comment: see https://github.com/plasm/the-wall/issues/7 seems it doesnt work as i wish

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so it seems you would have to do something like the following:

1. Use `wall.setCallOnUpdate( myFunctionUpdate );` ([this](http://wall.plasm.it/documentation/#wall%3asetCallOnUpdate)) to update all newly generated images so that they have the rel=lightbox attribute set.
2. Reinitialize slimbox.

--OR--

You could simply use the `CallOnUpdate` to directly enable the slimbox on items using the [API](http://code.google.com/p/slimbox/wiki/MooToolsAPI)

Comment: They have already the rel=lightbox since the generation  but how to reinitialize?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Event Delegation - this is how I got my wall working with lightbox. I called this after the initWall() method and also the changeOnUpdate() so the new events would be added.

```
var boundClicker;   


          $$('div.tile a').each(function(button) {


              var linkDest = button.get('href');
              var title = button.get('data-title');
              var type = button.get('rel');

              var clicker = function(event)
              {
                  event.stop();
                  Mediabox.open(linkDest, title, '470 290');
              };
              boundClicker = clicker.bind(button);
              button.addEvent('click', boundClicker);

           });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a "click" event handler and use the getMovement function.

```
items.each(function(item) {
item.addEvent("click",function(e){
if( wall.getMovement() ){
    e.stop();
    }
    else {
            Mediabox.open(...);
    }
}); }
```